# ng-view outside of index file

Tags: php, angularjs

I am building a project for a client who has a php site, there is a file that has "template functions". ...so basically, the person has different HTML pages wrapped inside of PHP functions. I need to build a template inside of this person's weird site and I REALLY want to use AngularJs. So at the top of the file is all this stuff, which not exactly sure what it is doing but basically setting where the site is and what template to use.

My question - I am getting Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error. My Angularjs code is fine I am pretty sure. I have ng-app, and ng-view..just basic stuff in place. Does anyone know possibilities why I am getting this error? I am thinking it must have something to do with this wacky server/php setup. Also any ideas to make it work?

Inside of the php function that loads the template for the site what looks like a basic HTML file with ng-app on the html tags and and ng-view div.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
function setup_path_massage(){
    if (substr_count($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],".") == 1){
       $domref = "www." . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ; }
    else {
       $domref =          $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ; }
    list($host,$domain,$ext) = split("\.",$domref);
    $domain .= "." . $ext;
     $_SESSION['settings']['domain'] = $domain;
    #################
    if (isset($_SERVER['SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT'])){
        $orig_path_info = realpath($_SERVER['SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
        $pos = strpos($orig_path_info, '/shop/');
    }
    else {
       $orig_path_info = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
       $pos = strpos($orig_path_info, '/shop/');
   }
   $shop_path  = substr($orig_path_info, 0, $pos)."/shop/";
   $Zend_path  = $shop_path . 'Zend/library/';
    $version    = 'v' . substr($orig_path_info, $pos + 7, strpos($orig_path_info, '/', $pos + 7) - ($pos + 7));

   set_include_path($shop_path.$version.'/:'.$Zend_path);
   return array ($host,$domain);
   }
  list($host,$domain) = setup_path_massage();
```

Comment: if possible can you post the AngularJS part,..coz the problem is related to AngularJS injector...so it must be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was just spazzing out. ...I forgot to attach angular-routes.js and was trying to set up routes.